# How to override the system default value for the duration when LED will be on

Tags: android, led

I have written a small test app (borrowed examples from previous implementation given in Stack Overflow) that will turn on Notification LED on my tablet . When I test this app on the tablet its not working as desired , i.e the LED turns on for a very small amount of time (and not for the 5 seconds duration that I have mentioned in my program). I guess its taking the system default value for the duration for which the LED needs to be ON/OFF rather than taking the value specified in my app. Has anyone seen a similar problem earlier ? Is there a way for me to override this system specific value ? My code is as below :

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);
    RedFlashLight();
}

private void RedFlashLight()
{
    NotificationManager nm = ( NotificationManager ) getSystemService( NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
    Notification notif = new Notification();
    notif.ledARGB = Color.RED;
    notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS ;
    notif.ledOnMS = 5000; //5 seconds 
    notif.ledOffMS = 0;  //do not turn it off 
    nm.notify(10, notif);
 }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way for me to override this system specific value ?

Beyond what you are already doing? No.

Bear in mind:

- Not all devices have LEDs
- Not all devices that do have LEDs will necessarily use them for notifications
- Device manufacturers can otherwise ignore the requests in the `Notification` object, such as LED color

So, you can ask for whatever you want, and whether you get it will depend on the device.

Comment: I see , I tested this app on my Motorola Phone and it works , however on the Motorola XYboard it does not  work . So that means the same manufacturer and different hardware the behavior is different ? Is there any other way to keep the LED turned on for a longer duration ?

Comment: @user1932046 You could even end up with different versions of the manufacturer provided firmware on the same device acting differently. You can't, unfortunately, depend on it in the slightest.

Comment: @user1932046: "So that means the same manufacturer and different hardware the behavior is different ?" -- sure. Even the same device might behave differently before and after firmware updates. LED behavior is completely up to the device manufacturer. You can only suggest things that may or may not be honored. "Is there any other way to keep the LED turned on for a longer duration ?" -- no, sorry. Again, bear in mind that many devices do not have an LED at all.